# Error due to using single quotes in htmlspecialchars and htmlentities in php

Tags: php, html, string

Well it is pretty much straight forward to encode or skip different html characters by using:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<b>"name"</b>', ENT_QUOTES).'<br>';
```

or

```
echo htmlentities('<b>"name"</b>', ENT_QUOTES).'<br>';
```

These both statements work fine. But when I add single quotes `''` inside the string like:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<b>"'name'"</b>', ENT_QUOTES).'<br>';
```

or

```
echo htmlentities('<b>"'name'"</b>', ENT_QUOTES).'<br>';
```

Then in such case it gives an error. Here I need to allow these single quotes inside that string. Please show me how to make allow the single quotes `''` inside string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `'` with `\`. So try the following solution:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<b>"\'name\'"</b>', ENT_QUOTES).'<br>';
echo htmlentities('<b>"\'name\'"</b>', ENT_QUOTES).'<br>';
```

The other way using `"` for parameter would look like the following:

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<b>\"'name'\"</b>", ENT_QUOTES).'<br>';
echo htmlentities("<b>\"'name'\"</b>", ENT_QUOTES).'<br>';
```